# Jquery Resizable Image size issue

Tags: jquery, image, resizable

Image size is not automatically detected when using jquery resizable. Both  Firefox and IE displays the image much smaller, and chrome show nothing at all. I can't seem to find a direct answer to this issue. How can this be fixed.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

  <img src="http://www.carsyouwilldrive.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/futurecar1.jpg"> <script type="text/javascript">
$("img").resizable();
  </script>
```

Comment: can you send a link to the page, or alternatively the code for the rest of the page? thanks :)

Comment: There is no page or rest of the code. Just run this code above to see what i'm taking about.

Comment: @alex Shows up fine in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/cLWcx/

Comment: original dimensions: 450px×338px... Initial rendered dimensions: 450x338

Comment: The image dimension is 450px × 338px. That's not how it's showing in your jsfiddle link. It's showing as a small icon. That's how it's showing in firefox and IE. In Chrome it doesn't show at all. Do couple of refreshes in case you have the image cached.

Comment: I think you've got to either set the image dimensions in the element or wait for the image to load before calling resizable... how else is jQuery going to know how big it is?

Comment: @alex No caching here, cleared all my history, cache etc, still shows up as the full image. what version of FF you using? I'm on 3.6.13... screenshot: http://picasaweb.google.com/Damien.L.Wright/Screenshots?authkey=Gv1sRgCISBtbnBqOLEeg#5561147553001598002

Comment: The img tag will be loaded dynamically, so no way of knowing deminsions. Damien, please try chrome and IE. I have the latest versions of all browsers.

Comment: @alex I removed my answer, naveen's answer below is the best fix. btw +1 for the question, is a doozy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why webkit is acting like this.

Workaround is to ensure that resizable is called after the [`load-event`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) of image is completed.

```
$("img").load(function () {
    $("img").resizable();
});
```

On an unrelated side note it would be better if you

1. give the image an id and call it
   with that id
2. close the img tag properly

Comment: Incredibly elegent answer, much better than the one I had here... +1 :)

Comment: no worries :) I'm honestly not too sure... seems strange that I could see it in FF but alex only saw the thumbnail... hmmm..

Answer (score 0):

@alex shows right way to resize image. I tested on Chrome it shows actual height & width. please reconfigure your browser. sometimes browser not configure well.. so it occurs.. please check code http://bit.ly/gM8sSD

Comment: I would remove the link to the jsfiddle from my previous answer, it was a hacky solution that is not as good at naveen's